# TeamCity Notifications - Message object properties

Tags: teamcity, freemarker, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to customize the [email notifications](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications) sent by TeamCity and it works well but I don't find the documentation and description about the components of the message object.

```
<#list build.buildLog.messages[1..] as message><#-- skipping the first message (it is a root node)-->
  <#if message.status == "ERROR" || message.status == "FAILURE" >
    ${message.text} // What are other components of message ?
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Any idea where I can found them and all the object types available ?
Thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get info about predefined beans (`build`, `project`, `buildType`, etc) [see documentation page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications#CustomizingNotifications-DefaultDataModel).

And using [TeamCity javadoc](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/current) you could find appropriate methods / return value types.

As answering your question, 
`message` is instance of [`jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.buildLog.LogMessage` class](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/current/jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/buildLog/LogMessage.html) and have `text`, `status`, `timestamp`, `level`, `flowId` and other components.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about TeamCity specifically, but you might be able to loop through the properties of `message`. Something like this:

```
<#list message?keys as key>
    ${key} - ${message[key]}<br>
</#list>
```

Reference: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html